# Auto insert values to table from range

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to auto insert values into a table i.e. from 30 to 200 with MySQL statement ?

Comment: are you looking to add 170 new rows to your table?

Comment: Exacly. It will be nice to have a way to specify values on other columns too - for example table: `id, col_with_range, value` and set `value` to `"abc"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a stored procedure that should do it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_range()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 30;
  WHILE i <= 200 DO
    INSERT my_table (col_with_range) VALUES (i);
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about creating ranges with a SQL statement, but you can very quickly generate a set of data with http://www.generatedata.com/ and run the query to insert it all into your database.

You can have it output the data in SQL format so you just copy & paste into whatever you use to interface with your database. (phpMyAdmin in my case)

Answer (score 1):

I find bulk-insert tasks more manageable when using a programming language to help out.

For example, Python can do what you want in a few lines:

```
>>> import MySQLdb # import the MySQLdb module
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(passwd='mypassword', db='mydb', user='myusername')

>>> mylist = [(i,'abc') for i in range(30,201)] # create list w/ values to insert

>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> curs.executemany('''INSERT INTO mytable 
...   (col_with_range, val) VALUES (%s, %s)''', mylist)
171L
```

And you're done:

```
>>> curs.execute('SELECT col_with_range, val FROM mytable')
171L
>>> curs.fetchall()
(('30', 'abc'), ('31', 'abc'), ('32', 'abc'), ('33', 'abc'), etc., etc., etc.
>>> curs.close()
>>> conn.close()
```

Comment: @hsz:  sure. Just providing another option :-)