# How can I insert rows in a table where 2 fields are the same and the third is defined by a list of values

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I have a mysql table with fields of the form (id, contact_id, fruit, preference_no)

Id is auto-incrementing,  contact_id, fruit and preference_no can take many values.

I want to insert many rows into this table.  These rows all have fruit = 'apple' and preference_no = '7" but the value for contact_id is to to be drawn from a list of numbers  ie contact_id in (523, 525, 526, 539,...)

So the first row to insert would be (523,'apple',7) and the second row would be (525,'apple', 7) etc

Is there a quick way to do this using MySQL?

Can I do something with parameters?

Eg Insert into table (contact_id, fruit, preference_no) select @param, 'apple', 7 where @param = (523,525,526,539,...)

Comment: From where are coming this data? from another table? from application? etc. ?

Comment: It is just a list of values  (523,526,528,531,...). so i want to insert (523, apple, 7) as one row and (526, apple, 7) as another row etc.

Comment: So, if value_2 and value_3 are same, you want just ignore and not insert?

Comment: Use of a scripting language like PHP is the best option.

Comment: Question reworded to clarify the problem.

Comment: what about a stored `procedure similar` to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075887/auto-insert-values-to-table-from-range but in yours add apple and 7 to the insert part?

Answer (score -1):

Multiple inserts are done like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
  tablename  
  (contact_id, fruit, preference_no)
VALUES 
  (523, 'apple', 7), (526, 'apple', 7) ...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a quick way when there are over 300 rows to insert.

Comment: @JoAnne There's​ no quick way. Maybe You want to look at `LOAD DATA INFILE` ? In Enterprise grade apps such things done by queueing (rabbitmq, amqp, rsmq)

Answer (score -1):

Alter table to make 'Apple' and '7' as default values of `fruit` and `preference_no` then iterate into list to produce the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (contact_id) VALUES 
(523),(525),(526),(539)
```